# How to remove files based on a certain pattern from a certain year

Tags: unix, grep, find, rm

I want to delete files that contain ak anywhere in their file name from 2017 or 2016 or any other random year. I know this is wrong as I don't think you can pipe to an rm command. If find may be better I am open to suggestions

```
ls -ltr *ak* | grep '2017' | rm -rf
```

ls -ltr (contain x anywhere in file name) | grep (x year) | rm -rf
This however doesn't do anything

```
-rw-rw----   1   abinitio       0 2017 13:49 ks
-rw-rw----   1   abinitio       0 Sep 26 13:49 ks.txt
-rw-rw----   1   abinitio       0 Oct  3 15:35 a.txt
-rw-rw----   1   abinitio       0 Oct  3 15:35 abak.txt
-rw-rw----   1   abinitio       0 Oct  3 15:36 raks.txt
-rw-rw----   1   abinitio       0 Oct  3 15:36 aks.txt
```

so this is my output my command was trying to grep the date from here it should return and delete

```
-rw-rw----   1   abinitio       0 Oct  3 15:35 abak.txt
-rw-rw----   1   abinitio       0 Oct  3 15:36 raks.txt
-rw-rw----   1   abinitio       0 Oct  3 15:36 aks.txt
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 1):

> When you are talking about "the date on filename", it seems you mean
>   "from a past year".

You can remove files with "[find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73268/how-to-move-the-files-based-on-year)" filtering the exact dates you need

```
find . -name "*ak*" -newermt $DATEA -not -newermt $DATEB -exec rm {} \+
```

Check it working:

```
$ cat script.sh
  DATEA=$1
  DATEB=$2
  find . -name "*ak*" -newermt $DATEA -not -newermt $DATEB -exec rm {} \+
$ ls -lrta
 total 0
 -rw-rw-rw- 1 unixuser unixuser   0 Dec 31  2011 ak1
 -rw-rw-rw- 1 unixuser unixuser   0 Dec 31  2012 ak2
 -rw-rw-rw- 1 unixuser unixuser   0 Dec 31  2018 ak3
 drwxrwxrwx 1 unixuser unixuser 512 Oct  4 02:21 ..
 -rw-rw-rw- 1 unixuser unixuser   0 Oct  4 02:24 ak
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 unixuser unixuser 115 Oct  4 02:25 script.sh
 drwxrwxrwx 1 unixuser unixuser 512 Oct  4 02:25 .
$ ./script.sh 20120101 20190101
$ ls -lrta
total 0
-rw-rw-rw- 1 unixuser unixuser   0 Dec 31  2011 ak1
drwxrwxrwx 1 unixuser unixuser 512 Oct  4 02:21 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 unixuser unixuser   0 Oct  4 02:24 ak
-rwxrwxrwx 1 unixuser unixuser 115 Oct  4 02:25 script.sh
drwxrwxrwx 1 unixuser unixuser 512 Oct  4 02:25 .
$
```

Comment: The `find` is a reasonable approach but the loop implementation isn't - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: hahhaha @EdMorton It was late, and I'm not an awk / sed god as you !!!! :)

Comment: you mean -xargs??

Comment: @EdMorton, now I underrstand -with exec is better!!! :)   Please correct me if I am on a mistake!!! thanks a lot for your culture and shared knowledge

Comment: `-exec` or `xargs` are good or even a loop implemented as shown in that FAQ rather than as you had it written would be OK. You don't need to escape the `+` btw.

Answer (score -1):

this command will help you.
be carefull

```html
 ls -ltr --full-time  *ak*  | grep '2017' | awk '{print $9}' | xargs rm -rf
```

another guaranty way filtering date and file name

```html
ls -ltr --full-time  *ak* | awk '{print $6,  $9}'  | grep '2017' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: Hello @EdMorton I felt like a bad student :)

Comment: I actually wanted to show question "xargs rm -rf" why this command didn't work.

Comment: @ErdalTuran, Ed is a great guy with great knowledge!! always read his posts and consider his opinion!! :) he makes all of us learning!!